# Applications start logs

Tags: ssh, log

I have a simple question. Where can I find a log that contains information about application launch?

For the context: I have a terminal server and a client connected to it via ssh. I want to know which application was started by the user and when. I've searched through all the /var/log journals but without success. Now I question myself if it is even supposed to be there.

To be as clear as possible, I want a journal, that will write down something like "gnome-paint was launched at 12:21 by User1"

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/222912/how-can-i-log-all-process-launches-in-linux

Comment: It isn't there by default, but you can set up auditing for it. The auditing *will most probably* slow down your server.